# C++ why am I getting this strange error for no matching function call

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have the following code segment:

UnaryExpression.h:

```cpp
#ifndef UNARYEXPRESSION_H_
#define UNARYEXPRESSION_H_

#include "Expression.h"

class UnaryExpression : public Expression {
private:
    Token op;
    Expression exp;
protected:
    std::map<std::string, float> scope;
public:
    UnaryExpression(std::map<std::string, float> &scope, Token& op, Expression& exp);
    virtual ~UnaryExpression();

    void evaluate();
    float getReturnValue();
};

#endif /* UNARYEXPRESSION_H_ */
```

UnaryExpression.cpp:

```cpp
#include "UnaryExpression.h"

UnaryExpression::UnaryExpression(std::map<std::string, float> &scope, Token& op, Expression& exp) : Expression(scope) {
    this->op = op;
    this->exp = exp;
}

UnaryExpression::~UnaryExpression() {}

void UnaryExpression::evaluate() {}

float UnaryExpression::getReturnValue() {
    return this->returnResult;
}
```

I am constantly getting an error, but as soon as I remove `Expression exp;` from the constructor and private variables, the error seems to dissapear and I'm not sure why this is happening:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\UnaryExpression.o" "..\\src\\UnaryExpression.cpp" 

..\src\UnaryExpression.cpp: In constructor 'UnaryExpression::UnaryExpression(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, float>&, Token&, Expression&)':
..\src\UnaryExpression.cpp:10:117: error: no matching function for call to 'Expression::Expression()'
   10 | UnaryExpression::UnaryExpression(std::map<std::string, float> &scope, Token& op, Expression& exp) : Expression(scope) {
      |                                                                                                                     ^
In file included from ..\src\UnaryExpression.h:11,
                 from ..\src\UnaryExpression.cpp:8:
..\src\Expression.h:18:2: note: candidate: 'Expression::Expression(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, float>&)'
   18 |  Expression(std::map<std::string, float> &scope);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
..\src\Expression.h:18:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
..\src\Expression.h:13:7: note: candidate: 'Expression::Expression(const Expression&)'
   13 | class Expression : public Statement {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
..\src\Expression.h:13:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.89ms)
```

For reference, here is the definition of Expression.h:

```cpp
#ifndef EXPRESSION_H_
#define EXPRESSION_H_

#include "Statement.h"

class Expression : public Statement {
protected:
    std::map<std::string, float> scope;
    float returnResult;
public:
    Expression(std::map<std::string, float> &scope);
    virtual ~Expression();

    virtual void evaluate();
    virtual float getReturnValue();
};

#endif /* EXPRESSION_H_ */
```

The class Statement is similar to Expression, it has only a virtual method `void evaluate()` and a scope. When I initialize Expression, of course I pass the scope to the parent Statement class.

Comment: Out of curiosity: The member `scope` in the `UnaryExpression`, is it a copy/paste mistake? There is already such member in the base class `Expression`.

Comment: `UnaryExpression` has a field `Expression exp` that your constructor is not initializing.

Comment: @al3c Correct! :-) [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3fcc63c1f76f21e) (I must admit that the complaints of g++ were somehow misleading me.) A nice example that initializers should be preferred over assignment in constructor's body...

Comment: @Scheff yes, thanks for pointing it out, fixed it. al3c You are correct, I know that this is the error, but I wanted to simulate the following behaviour UnaryExpression(Number(1),-), so Number(1) is expression itself and after evaluation the result would be -1. I want to pass an additional expression as an argument in the constructor as well. How should I do this?

Comment: Did you notice that I fixed the issue mentioned by @al3c in the linked [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3fcc63c1f76f21e)? You just have to pass the argument `exp` into the constructor of `this->exp` (as I did). If you don't then `UnaryExpression::exp` is default-constructed. (Every member is always constructed - either explicitly or implicitly.) That's the error you ran into. (IMHO, the complaints of g++ are a bit misleading concerning this.)

Comment: @Scheff Yes, I actually just noticed it. I'm not experienced with C++ and I had no idea that this syntax was a thing.

Comment: Yepp. This is called [Member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and the preferable kind of construction of members, and not to confuse with [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). It's a bit tricky as member and arg. are called the same, and it works for all that because in the member initializer lists, only members are expected but in the member initializer arguments, the constructor arguments eclipse the members. That's the secret of why `exp(exp)` works. :-)